# Indefinite Limit for $f(x)$ and $f(1/x)$

Tags: calculus, limits

The problem is the following:
Prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=\infty$ if and only if $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}f(1/x)=\infty$.

**What I did:**

I'm able to prove that these two have the same limit, but I'm not sure I can use just this proof as a limit being "equal" $\infty$ is a nice way to say that it "does not exist".

Comment: Your statement currently doesn't make sense; "if and only if $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(1/x)$"... What about the limit?

Comment: $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \infty$ is defined as $\forall L: \exists N: x > N \implies f(x) > L$. Nothing about $\infty$ being a number.

Comment: Note that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x}$ exist and is $\infty$ is not the same that saying the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry, I had mistyped. Now it's correct. Thank you @KennyLau, that was precisely my doubt!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assuming $\lim_{x\to 0} f(\frac{1}{x})=\infty$

Replace $x=\frac{1}{u}$

$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{u\to o^+}f(\frac{1}{u})=\lim_{x\to o^+}f(\frac{1}{x})=+\infty$

Comment: You forgot the "if" part...